# Using the Content of Textbox as a variable in VB (2012)

Tags: vb.net, variables, textbox

In the code below b textbox will contain the string "a.text" what I want b textbox to be the evaluation of the content of the string "a.text" which is the word Test.  Please don't suggest:
 `b.text = a.text`

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim t As String
    a.Text = "Test"
    t = "a.text"
    b.Text = t
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Is "a" a textbox?  Or is it a variable?  What I think you are asking is that "a" (a textbox) contains the string "Test.", you then are assigning that value to the variable "t".  Then, you are trying to assign that variable to the Text property in "b".  Is that correct?  Or are you trying to parse the string "a.Text" to mean grab the contents of the "a" textbox and get its Text Property.  In other words, are you looking to cast a string to a controls properties?  Question as above is confusing.

Comment: Sorry A and b are both text boxes

Comment: You could do this using reflection but are you sure this is the best solution to the problem.

Comment: The code is more complicated that the example basically the name of the text box will be "constructed" in a string variable then I need this string variable when placed on the right hand side of an equal sign to show the content of the "constructed" text box.

Comment: Would a case statement serve in this instance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the case statment?

Comment: `Select Case t` `Case "a"` `b.Text() = a.Text()` `case "c"` `b.Text() = c.Text()` `End Select`

Comment: no that doesn't help.  The form has 25 text boxes on it name QAR1 to QAR25 that need to be save to the database and I trying to find an easy way to do this other than   Field1=QAR1.Text Field2=QAR2.TEXT .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Controls collection of your form.  You can find an item based on its name.

Also check out this answer
[VB .NET Access a class property by string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191076/vb-net-access-a-class-property-by-string-value)

So, you could take your string, split it by the ".", find the control using the Controls Collection, and then get the property using the second half of your string using Reflection.

Of course, if you are just looking for the Text of the textbox, you just need to use the collection and forget the reflection.  Like this..

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To 25
        .fields("Field" & i).value = Me.Controls("QAR" & i).Text
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you asked for using [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) ... I'm not an enormous fan of it for something like this, but here's how it would look in your code:

```
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        a.Text = "Hello"

        Dim t As String = "a.Text"

        b.Text = DirectCast(SetValue(t), String)
    End Sub

    Public Function SetValue(ByVal name As String) As Object

        Dim ctrl As Control = Me.Controls(name.Split("."c)(0))
        Return ctrl.GetType().GetProperty(name.Split("."c)(1)).GetValue(ctrl, Nothing)
    End Function
End Class
```

This would set textbox a's value to "Hello" and then copy that to textbox b using the reflection method.

Hope this helps!