# Acces object fields dynamically in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, object, field

I have an object with several fields:

address.kondition, address.sprache, address.waehrung and so on.

How can I access the fields in a function dynamically? I tried the following code, but address.field gives an error:

```
Private Sub fkt1()
    Dim address As New objAddress

    fkt2("Kondition", "1", address)
    fkt2("Sprache", "D", address)
End Sub

Private Sub fkt2(ByVal field As String, ByVal defaultvalue As String, ByVal address As objAddress)
    If address.field = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Not defined")
        address.field = defaultvalue
    Else
        ...
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error?  Is field an integer or a string?  You use both types against it.

Comment: Ahhh!  The old "gives an error" problem.  If I had a shilling for every time...

Comment: The error is that "field is not a member of objAddress" as There doesn't exist a field "address.field". "Field" should represent "Kondition" or "Sprache" as "field" is a variable which can contain the string "Sprache" for example. By the way: Kondition is an integer and Sprache is a String

Comment: Check the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191076/vb-net-access-a-class-property-by-string-value).  Should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Edit your post to show us your objAddress class.  While you are editing the post, include your error message that you posted in the comments.